# multiple modals on my page shows the same images

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have been researching trying to figure out why its doing this, maybe I just dont understand modals. IDK.

Anyways what is happening is I started with a light box: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

and changed the body to:

```
<body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Title</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%"                     
             onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" 
             class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
     <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
     <div class="modal-content">

         <div class="mySlides">
             <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
             <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides">
             <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
             <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides">
             <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
             <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides">
             <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
             <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
         </div>

         <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
         <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

         <div class="caption-container">
             <p id="caption"></p>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

to create a single image in the modal, and to scroll through it.  I love it, and I thought that it would solve my issue. Alas

When I implemented it in my web page it worked. but then I copied and pasted, and it in another area of the page, changed the images, but it is still showing the original images from the first modal.  So I dont know where to turn.

I have 0 experience in jscript, jquery.  (those classes are yet to come in my schooling...).

I was thinking:
1.) have the images on an external html page and import that I have looked at AJAX, but im confused. (dont necessarily want to use bootstrap)

I have looked at these resources, and they kinda help but again, I dont know how to craft them to my needs.

[using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663555/bootstrap-3-how-to-load-content-in-modal-body-via-ajax)
[modals, nonimported html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427926/using-multiple-modal-dialogs-in-one-page)
[modals](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-get-this-script-to-work-for-multiple-modal-popups/252443)

See the Pen [Work issue](https://codepen.io/Kardee785/pen/gevaWp/) by Michael Barnhouse ([@Kardee785](https://codepen.io/Kardee785)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Its showing the same images because your `<img src` attribute values are the same. If you want to show different images your `src` attribute needs to be different like so `img_nature_wide1.jpg`, `img_nature_wide2.jpg`, `img_nature_wide3.jpg` etc... Make sure the value matches whatever your image file name is or it won't load the images.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I did change the <img src >ie.
<img src="zelda1.png">
    blah
<img src="zelda2.png>
    blah
but it will always show the images in the modal for zelda1.png

Comment: I added a code pen reference of the structure of my code, I couldn't load the images, but the src are different (also only the first 3 sections of transfers are the only ones with the modal) showing the same images

Comment: Is the `id` attribute of the new `.modal` element unique?

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal"> is the same on all 3 modals. I was assuming that this just called a div "my modal" and applied the css for modal to it.      Is it seriously something as simple as that?      
UPDATE Tried to change the <div id="myModal" class="modal"> to something like <div id="Transfers" class="modal"> and <div id="RecurringTransfers" class="modal"> it broke the modal, the images didnt show any longer

Comment: Thought that it might be a java script issue (probably is) where it was calling the same id=myModal 3 different times. as the previous statement , I changed the html ID's but didn't add an open close in the .js file.  added those.  and still received the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Curious 13, and Nate Whittaker Suggested I needed to make each section have its own unique Id.  I had posted that that didn't work, and the reason it didnt work was because my .js wasnt reading/importing what to display.  So I had to create a var in js (named modalId), and then call that information into the opening, closing, and navigating of the modal.

Here is the .js, I had one of my friends help me with.

```
function openModal(modalId) {
  document.getElementById(modalId).style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal(modalId) {
  document.getElementById(modalId).style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(modalId, n) {
  showSlides(modalId, slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(modalId, n) {
  showSlides(modalId, slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(modalId, n) {
  var i;
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
  var slides = modal.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```